# Can a question go completely missing?

Tags: support, questions, migration

This has happened to me with a question titled "Understand error codes in Linux".

I asked this question, one user commented to migrate it to Unix/Linux section..another user answered it very correctly. Along with me one more person +voted for that answer and after a total of 4 comments to that answer, I accepted that answer and marked accordingly..
And now I see that question is NOT listed anywhere...neither under StackOverflow nor under Unix/Linux.

Can somebody explain this to me...?

Comment: Was it ever really there?

Comment: It got moved 25 seconds ago: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8355/understand-error-codes-in-linux

Comment: Yes, I just saw that..I think when migration happens, it would be good to notify the original place (SO in my case) of this change.

Comment: There is a recently implemented system which does actually alert the author of a question about migration, via top-bar announcement. It might not be immediate, though.

Comment: Thanks, @random - it was nice one! +1 from myside :) @Grace Note: Thank you for letting know this feature. Yes, later I saw that..as you rightly said it was shown much later..this question cropped up in between that time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that got deleted, which makes it only visible to users with over 10k rep.  I undeleted it and migrated it to Unix and Linux for you.  [Understand error codes in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8355/understand-error-codes-in-linux)

Comment: Thanks @Bill the Lizard! Any reason it got deleted?? I can understand migration..though!

Comment: @TheCottonSilk: It was closed as 'off-topic' so I can only assume that was also the reason for deletion.

Comment: I think we the users need to take actions diligently after understanding the true meanings of close, migrate and delete.